# JQuery click function requiring 2 clicks

Tags: jquery

I've recently encountered a problem, and despite coming across similar questions here alreadt, none of the answers provided appear to work for me.

I have a jQuery click function, and an 'onclick' function on the same link (it shows a hidden div, and pops up a window - the intention being for both to happen at the same time).  At the moment, when the link is clicked, the popup works fine, but it requires a second click for the hidden div to show - the popup showing again on that second click.

I've tried a few things, like moving the script to the bottom of the page (didn't work at all), and also removing the onclick event altogether - but the 'show' aspect always seems to require 2 clicks.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!  My code is below;

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(".show").click(function(){
var left = $(this).next('span').css('left');
if ( left == '3px') {
$(this).next('span').animate({left:'148px'}, 1000);
} else {
$(this).next('span').animate({left:'3px'}, 1000);
}
return false;
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showPopup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=190,width=520,top=200,left=300,resizable');
if (window.focus) {this.window.focus()}
}
</script>

<!--- In Page --->
<div class="coupon"><a href="/relevantpage.html" onclick="showPopup(this.href);return(false);"   class="show"></a><span class="code">ABC1</span></div>
```

Comment: I would avoid using `onclick=` and jQuery `click` handler ... you might get unexpected results (pretty much like you are now) ...

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you cant show the div in the click-function or am I misinterpreting your question entirely? Or is the question "How to not make the popup popup twice?"

Comment: Make sure that `$(this).next('span').css('left')` actually === "3px" when you are clicking it the first time, because otherwise, the first click will be used to set it to 3px (you might not notice this, if it is for example at 2px and set to 3px), and only after that will it actually set it to 148px on the next click (as it is set to 3px now)

Comment: @limelights - no, there's no particular reason, I'm simply re-using code I picked up elsewhere, and my JS/jQuery knowledge is somewhat limited!

Comment: @Niklas - you and Linus (below) both nailed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that it might not have anything to do with the click handler, but that on your first click, `left` will not equal `'3px'`, but something else (perhaps `'auto'`?). But it will be in the same position, so you won't see the animation. Next time, you will see when it animates to `'148px'`. It might be cleaner to toggle a class after the animation, and check for that.

Comment: Thanks Linus - you were indeed correct, the 3px was the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the `onclick` event and do all the stuff in the jQuery [click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

I also had an equal problem using both events. So try to move the `showPopup` function in the click event.

```
 $(".show").click(function(){

   showPopup($(this).attr("href"));

   var left = $(this).next('span').css('left');
      if ( left == '3px') {
         $(this).next('span').animate({left:'148px'}, 1000);
      } else {
         $(this).next('span').animate({left:'3px'}, 1000);
     }
   return false;
});
```

Here you can see an example of your code *(other pixel values)* to check, if this is the correct behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/tQGxZ/1/

Comment: Thanks Keith - ideally I'd like to do as you suggest and have only the one function.  I tried your code, however that appears to only be going to the href (in the same page, not the popup) and ignoring the 'show'

Comment: don't know, if I have understood your question, but have a look on my edit.

Comment: Thanks again Keith - I'd missed off the actual function for showPopup when I tried it last.  The original issue was unrelated to this, but I'm going to use your suggestion in any event as it does clean things up - thanks.

Comment: .click is deprecated, since jQuery 1.6.x, it just links to the new .on function. The optimal way to create click events is: $('.show').on('click', function() { //do stuff here }